# SQL: How to pass mutliple select queries to an sql Function

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I have the two select queries below :

```
SELECT column_1 FROM table_name WHERE **column_2= 'X'** AND scope= 'scope';
SELECT column_1 FROM table_name WHERE **column_2= 'Y'** AND scope='scope';
```

I want to pass each of the above queries to a **predefined SQL method**:

So far only the following syntax has worked, but in this case it is just passing the same value to both parameters:

```
select function_name(table_name.column_1, table_name.column_1) FROM table_name
WHERE column_2= 'X' AND scope='scope';
```

I would like to do something like this but it is not working:

```
select function_name(SELECT column_1 FROM table_name WHERE **column_2= 'X'** AND
scope= 'scope', SELECT column_1 FROM table_name WHERE **column_2= 'Y'** AND 
scope='scope');
```

Comment: "How to pass mutliple select queries to an sql Function
" - Answer: don't!

Answer (score 0):

You can try-

```
SELECT column_1 FROM table_name WHERE column_2= 'X' OR column_2= 'Y' AND scope= 'scope';
```

As the resulting column is same and also the query table is same you can combine the two conditions.